# How do you toggle an active state ng-class in an ng-repeat item using ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="image in images" data-ng-click="toggle = !toggle" data-ng-init="toggle=false">
      <img data-ng-class="{'active' : toggle}" src="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS for 'active' class is from bootstrap. 
So toggling works, which is almost where I want it; I would like it similar to active states in navigation links, except in my example it's dealing with images so need to worry about url strings, etc.

I tried emulating this example found here to no avail (I tried the same logic for images): [ng-class to highlight active menu item based on ng-repeat. AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943217/ng-class-to-highlight-active-menu-item-based-on-ng-repeat-angularjs)

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What i would do in your situation is define an object inside the parent scope of that ng-repeat, and assign the index or whatever you wish to a propperty of that object. That is because objects work by reference in javascript, which means that the ng-click will actually update the parent scope attribute instead of redefine it.
Example at plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/oA12yLIb3RnlSYe6JxhI?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <style>
        .active{
            background-color: red;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="HolaCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="image in images" data-ng-click="toggleObject.item = $index">a
         <img data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject.item == $index}" src="" /><br>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        function HolaCtrl($scope){
            $scope.images = [1,2,3];
            $scope.toggleObject = {item: -1};
        }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Cheers

Comment: Yea, I stated the code is working perfectly. What's undesirable is the multi-selection. It should be that when one image is clicked the other image is deselected. Just like this topic dealing with active menu items: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943217/ng-class-to-highlight-active-menu-item-based-on-ng-repeat-angularjs

Comment: THANK YOU! I was doing something wrong with $index because I wasn't referencing that object. Thank you so much!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in following way:

```
<body>
<style>
.blue{
    background:blue;
}
</style>
<div ng-app='my'>
  <div ng-controller='maincontroller as mainctrl'> 
    <div ng-repeat='item in mainctrl.arr'>
    <p ng-class='{"blue":mainctrl.bgcolor==item}'
    ng-click='mainctrl.addColor(item)'>
    item {{item}}
    </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('my',[])
app.controller('maincontroller',maincontroller)
function maincontroller(){
var mainctrl = this;
mainctrl.arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

mainctrl.addColor = function(data){
mainctrl.bgcolor = data
}
}
</script>
</body>
```