# Angular, how to set class to the clicked list item and remove from others li items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-class

I have this list where I'm trying to set class to the clicked list item (but class should be set only for clicked item).

I tried to do by this way but without luck:

```
<a href="" 
   ng-ctrl="ThemesCtrl" 
   ng-click="checkThemeContent(theme);" 
   ng-repeat="theme in themes" 
   ng-hide="theme[filterProp] !== filterValue" 
   class="list-group-item">
    <b>{{theme.name}}</b>
    <span class="themesListIcons">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> {{theme.avg_score}}
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> {{theme.count_of_cards}}
    </span>
</a>
```

How can i do it please in the right way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: seems similair http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559549/how-do-you-toggle-an-active-state-ng-class-in-an-ng-repeat-item-using-ng-click

Comment: try removing { } inside ng-class, or putting them twice: {{ }}

Comment: Is currentTheme a $scope var?  Might set it I'm checkThemeContent for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great. 
Sorry because I have not plunker account, so I must explain you on theoretical way.

George, you have to create function in controller that selects your item, for an example, in your case:

```
$scope.checkThemeContent = function (name) {
    $scope.selectedName = name;
}
```

After this step, you must only call this function in your HTML like this:

```
<a href="" 
   ng-class="{selected:theme.name==selectedName}"  
   ng-click="checkThemeContent(theme.name)" 
   ng-repeat="theme in themes" 
   class="list-group-item">
    <b>{{theme.name}}</b>
    <span class="themesListIcons">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> {{theme.avg_score}}
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> {{theme.count_of_cards}}
    </span>
</a>
```

Please take look on ng-click part. You have to pass some property ('theme.name') of item (in your case 'theme') from list ('themes'), because you can't compare objects.

In ng-class you must also pass the same property as in ng-click. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

you need change the syntax `ng-class` directive

```
<a href="" 
   ng-class="{'selected':$index==selectedIndex}"  
   ng-ctrl="ThemesCtrl" 
   ng-click="checkThemeContent(theme);currentTheme=theme" 
   ng-repeat="theme in themes" 
   ng-hide="theme[filterProp] !== filterValue" 
   class="list-group-item">
    <b>{{theme.name}}</b>
    <span class="themesListIcons">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> {{theme.avg_score}}
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> {{theme.count_of_cards}}
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: I updated question code because i don't have any variable named selectedIndex.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'selectedIndex' is your scope variable that represents your selected item in the controller and the 'selected' is your CSS class, try to change the ng-class part like this:

```
ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}"
```

Comment: I updated question code because i don't have any variable named selectedIndex