# How to combine ng-class checks and ng-click comparisons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-class

I have an ng-repeat where the first item needs to have the class selected, as well as clicking on each item then changes the selection.

```
<li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers"
    data-ng-class="{'selected':$first}"
    ng-click="selectTicker(ticker.ticker)">{{ticker.ticker}}</li>
```

^ This works to have the first item have the class of `selected` by default.

```
<li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers"
    data-ng-click="toggleTicker.item = $index"
    data-ng-class="{'selected':toggleTicker.item == $index}"
    ng-click="selectTicker(ticker.ticker)">{{ticker.ticker}}</li>
```

^ Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559549/how-do-you-toggle-an-active-state-ng-class-in-an-ng-repeat-item-using-ng-click). The above works to add the class of `selected` based on click, but the first item is no longer selected by default.

My question is how to combine both? I've tried the following which did not work:

```
data-ng-class="{'selected':$first && toggleObject.item == $index}"
```

My controller:

```
var vs = $scope;

ApiFactory.getWatchList().then(function(data) {
    vs.tickers = data.data.tickers;
    vs.toggleTicker = {item: -1};
    vs.toggleTicker.item = vs.tickers[0];
    vs.loadingDone = true;
    console.log(vs.tickers[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `item` to the object at index 0 in your controller, but everywhere else it seems to be a number.  If you just want to use the index (as your click sets it to the number), then try this:

```
var vs = $scope;

ApiFactory.getWatchList().then(function(data) {
    vs.tickers = data.data.tickers;
    vs.toggleTicker = {item: 0}; // set index 0 as the selected index
    vs.loadingDone = true;
    //console.log(vs.tickers[0]); // what if there are no items?
});
```

***html***:

```
<li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers"
    data-ng-click="toggleTicker.item = $index"
    data-ng-class="{'selected':toggleTicker.item == $index}"
    {{ticker.ticker}}
</li>
```

Using `$first` is bad because the same item will *always* be the first one (unless you re-order them).  Using `ng-click` and `data-ng-click` is bad because they are essentially identical, maybe only one will actually get called?

Answer (score 1):

That's not done in ng-class, but in the controller or ng-init:

```
data-ng-init="toggleObject.item = tickers[0]" 
data-ng-class="{'selected':toggleObject.item == $index}"
```

I still suggest you do it in the controller.

Comment: Thanks, trying it out now... just added my controller code to the question

Comment: You're welcome! So the controller solution would be something like this: `vs.toggleObject.item = vs.tickers[0]`

Comment: Hmm now neither is working, no errors :( updated my controller, will see if I can put together a simple plunkr

Comment: A plunker would be great, just hardcode your factory data so you don't waste your time on it.