# How to properly use ng-init with ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a row of buttons and want to initialize the first button as active (as the data associated with it is loaded in my controller's init function). The below HTML works great, but when I click the other two buttons the 'active' class remains on the first button. I want this button set as active on page load and then treated 'normally' (ie: if a different button is clicked remove active class from first button):

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active : isActive}" ng-init="isActive = true" type="button" ng-click="playerMap.clusterToggle(true)">Clustered</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="playerMap.clusterToggle(false)">Unclustered</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="heatmap" ng-click="playerMap.heatmap()">Heatmap</button>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you toggle an active state ng-class in an ng-repeat item using ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559549/how-do-you-toggle-an-active-state-ng-class-in-an-ng-repeat-item-using-ng-click)

Comment: The code for your `ng-click` function coudl be helpfull. We do'nt even know if you set `isActive` to `false` on it.

Comment: Is there a need to set active the other button, which was clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Should be simple as:

If you are using a loop then its even clean - just pass the index.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="isActive[0] ? 'active' : ''" ng-init="isActive[0]=true"  type="button" ng-click="toggleButton(isActive,0)">Clustered</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="isActive[1] ? 'active' : ''"  type="button" ng-click="toggleButton(isActive,1)">Unclustered</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="isActive[2] ? 'active' : ''"  type="button"  ng-click="toggleButton(isActive,2)">Heatmap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this does not answer your initial question, here is a working solution (not very efficient I have to say):

HTML:

```
<div class='container' ng-controller="GoingStack">
  <div switch class="button" ng-class="{'active-button': state}">1</div>
  <div switch class="button">2</div>
  <div switch class="button">3</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
app.controller('GoingStack', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.state = true;
}]);
var active = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
app.directive("switch", [function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('click', function(e){
            scope.state = false;
            active[0].classList.remove('active-button');
            element.addClass('active-button');
        });
     }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Agreed, not efficient and non-Anguler solution at all ;)